# Is there a way to automatically scroll to an element in ListView.builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

My goal is to scroll to the correct person when I tap the marker in GoogleMaps.
Each marker has already saved a reference to the respective index in the list, but i don't know how I can make the list scroll by itself.
Thanks for any help :)

[image: Screenshot of map & horizontal list]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can assign a [`GlobalKey`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) to the item you want to scroll to and make use of [`ScrollPosition.ensureVisible`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPosition/ensureVisible.html).

#### GlobalKey

You need the global key in order to access the [`RenderObject`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderObject-class.html) of your widget.
You will need to either store this global key as a variable in your `StatefulWidget` (preferrably).

#### [`ScrollController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html)

You will also need to store a scroll controller in order to scroll to the position of your list view.

---

Here is how you would do it in the [`State`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) of your widget:

```dart
final itemKey = GlobalKey();
final scrollController = ScrollController();

@override
void dispose() {
  scrollController.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // Return your widget tree in here.
  // I am only showing the ListView section.
  ...
  ListView(
    ...,
    controller: scrollController,
    // You can also use a builder list view or w/e else.
    // You only need to supply the GlobalKey to exactly one item.
    children: <Widget>[
       SomeWidget(
         key: itemKey,
         ...,
       ),
    ],
  )
  ...
}
```

Now, you will be able to scroll to your selected item:

```dart
scrollController.position.ensureVisible(
  itemKey.currentContext.findRenderObject()!,
  alignment: 0.5, // How far into view the item should be scrolled (between 0 and 1).
  duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
);
```

Comment: I am having error in calling `ensureVisible`, it isn't defined, can you tell me how to use/call it properly, I am newbie to Flutter. Thanks

Comment: @iKeepChangingName You need to call it on `scrollController.position`.

Comment: Hi there ! Where exactly would you call the scrollControll.position.ensureVisibile() method? I'm getting a NoSuchMethodError

Comment: try `Scrollable.ensureVisible(itemKey.currentContext)`

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot this looks like an interesting solution.  Could it be updated to work with null safety?  This might be the solution many of us are looking for but can't get it to work because `error: The argument type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'RenderObject'`

Comment: @Mark sure, I updated it - let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Ok got it to work using `Scrollable.ensureVisible(_scrollToThisKey.currentContext! ...`. For some reason doing directly on the scrollController didn't like the `RenderObject?` vs `RenderObject`

Comment: While this possibly fulfills OP's requirement I don't think this answers the original question about `ListView.builder` that builds its items lazily. So if an item has not yet been created I wonder if there is hardly any way in Flutter to jump to that. Should work with `ListView` because it generates its items beforehand unlike `ListView.builder` but certainly is not the most efficient approach for a long list of items.

Comment: It  does  not works  for listview builder

Comment: If I will have 500 items in a list view, do I need to to create 500 `GlobalKey`s? Don't you think is it expensive?

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `Scrollable` widget to scroll to specific widget:

```
Scrollable.ensureVisible(
  itemKey.currentContext,
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500)
);
```

itemKey is a `GlobalKey` which is assigned to `key` property of a widget

Comment: Hi there, where would you call this though?

Comment: In a function e.g: scrollToItem(GlobalKey key)

Comment: what if we want the option to scroll to multiple widgets instead of a single one?

Comment: You need to keep list of global keys for those widgets and when you want pass the key to above method to scroll to that specific widget.

Comment: thank you, i got it working.