# Flutter: Last Seen Option in Listview builder

Tags: flutter

I have a finite range in listview builder like 600 list tiles in one listviewbuilder and I want that every list tile has an option to bookmark/or last seen like list tile 114 so if the user will close the app and opens that listview builder again then will resume with that 114 list tile not from the start of that how can I do this plz answer this in detail?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `GlobalKey` and `ScrollController`.

Do check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59779241/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-scroll-to-an-element-in-listview-builder) for detailed solution.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

search of preserve scroll with global key

by default it will save the last activity within the app . whatever you navigate to others pages .

if you need to keep preserving even with app killing so use with it `shared preference`

for more datils see

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_Px9Dx-Rxw